# make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8888

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2, port

This error appears when i tried to restart apache

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8888 
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

I had a map server running at port 8888. I tried to do a Redirect so that a direct access of the map server from remote is redirected. The sites-available/domain_name file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain_name
        ...
</VirtualHost>

Listen *:8888 http
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName domain_name
    Redirect permanent / http://domain_name/
    ...
    </VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way to avoid this error and restart the apache server. The map server and apache running on same machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the error's clear: something else has already bound to that port, so Apache is unable to.

Comment: @MarcB is there any options that let us to run the two server at the same time on the same machine. Any config options in apache?

Comment: sure, use different ports. You cannot have two different programs binding to the same ip:port at the same time.

Comment: @MarcB there is a redirect part, which redirects any direct access to the map server running at port 8888. So i think the issue exists even switch to a different port ?

Comment: it doesn't matter. two programs cannot bind to the same port:ip at the same time. Doesn't matter what your redirector does. apache and your map thingie can NOT be using the same ip:port.